# Outlook bar auto size to tree control

Tags: visual-c++, autoresize, window-resize, mfc-feature-pack, treecontrol

I created an Outlook bar with tree controls and would like to have it auto size to always fully display the text of the tree control. Ideally the border in the picture would move so that "Healthcare Merchandising" is fully visible.

[image: DrillSizing]

newDimbar is a CMFCOutlookBar object created in CMainFrame.

I have tried stretching it:

```
void CTreeDrill::OnTvnItemexpanded(NMHDR *pNMHDR, LRESULT *pResult)
{
LPNMTREEVIEW pNMTreeView = reinterpret_cast<LPNMTREEVIEW>(pNMHDR);
HTREEITEM hItem = pNMTreeView->itemNew.hItem;
RECT treeRect;
GetItemRect(GetChildItem(hItem), &treeRect, FALSE);
CMainFrame *pMain = (CMainFrame*)AfxGetMainWnd();
int iStretch = treeRect.right;
pMain->m_ctlNewDimBar.StretchPane(iStretch, FALSE);
EnsureVisible(GetChildItem(hItem));
}
```

and using move:

```
void CTreeDrill::OnTvnItemexpanded(NMHDR *pNMHDR, LRESULT *pResult)
{
RECT treeRect;
RECT newRect;
RECT dimRect;
GetItemRect(GetChildItem(hItem), &treeRect, FALSE);
CMainFrame *pMain = (CMainFrame*)AfxGetMainWnd();
pMain->m_ctlNewDimBar.GetWindowRect(&dimRect);
newRect = dimRect;
newRect.right = treeRect.right;
pMain->m_ctlNewDimBar.MoveWindow(newRect);
EnsureVisible(GetChildItem(hItem));
}
```

without luck. What am I missing?

Comment: can you post a picture?

Comment: are your document's views tabbed?

Comment: It is an MDI application and I am using MDITabs, if that is what you mean?

Comment: yes, i found the solution, check it out in the answer section.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Solution

I'm happy i found it because this is something i would have to do too in the future, you need to use [CWnd::SetWindowPos](http://msdn.microsoft.com/it-it/library/a1yzfz6d.aspx) to change the [CMFCOutlookBar](http://msdn.microsoft.com/it-it/library/bb982639.aspx)'s size, check this [tutorial that has more infos](http://nickperrysays.wordpress.com/2011/06/27/moving-and-resizing-mfc-controls-at-run-time/), after you change the size of [CMFCOutlookBar](http://msdn.microsoft.com/it-it/library/bb982639.aspx) you will have to use [CFrameWndEx::RecalcLayout](http://msdn.microsoft.com/it-it/library/cc665495.aspx) method of the frame that contains the [CMFCOutlookBar](http://msdn.microsoft.com/it-it/library/bb982639.aspx).

### Why using [CWnd::SetWindowPos](http://msdn.microsoft.com/it-it/library/a1yzfz6d.aspx)?

i don't know, it's the only one that worked for me

### Why use [CFrameWndEx::RecalcLayout](http://msdn.microsoft.com/it-it/library/cc665495.aspx) and not only call RecalcLayout() of the [CMFCOutlookBar](http://msdn.microsoft.com/it-it/library/bb982639.aspx)?

Because if you just recalculate the layout of the [CMFCOutlookBar](http://msdn.microsoft.com/it-it/library/bb982639.aspx) only the [CMFCOutlookBar](http://msdn.microsoft.com/it-it/library/bb982639.aspx) will be updated and then if you have anything attached to the [CMFCOutlookBar](http://msdn.microsoft.com/it-it/library/bb982639.aspx) it will not recieve the changes, so you might end with your [CMFCOutlookBar](http://msdn.microsoft.com/it-it/library/bb982639.aspx) overlapping some other control or your document's view, calling [CFrameWndEx::RecalcLayout](http://msdn.microsoft.com/it-it/library/cc665495.aspx) will make the whole frame reacalculate and so if you have tabbed document views they will be updated/resized accordingly.

### Your case

you will have to calculate the whole width of the tree, not only the item, and then use the [CWnd::SetWindowPos](http://msdn.microsoft.com/it-it/library/a1yzfz6d.aspx) on the [CMFCOutlookBar](http://msdn.microsoft.com/it-it/library/bb982639.aspx) with the updated value width value but keeping the height of the [CMFCOutlookBar](http://msdn.microsoft.com/it-it/library/bb982639.aspx).

```
newDimbar.GetWindowRect(pos);
ScreenToClient(&pos);
UINT flags = SWP_NOZORDER | SWP_NOMOVE;
newDimbar.SetWindowPos(NULL, 0, 0, iNewWidth, pos.Height(), flags);
```